# calculate cells in app script to using in google sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have this function and run good:

```
function total(x,y)
    return x + y;
  }
```

in google sheet I add in any cell `=total(A1,B1)` and give me result.

I want to do same that to calculate a lot of cells by this code:

```
function total(x)
    return x;
  }
```

in google sheet I add in any cell `=total(A1:A100)` and give me error. any help for that problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function myTotal(a) {
  let r = a.flat().filter(e => e && !isNaN(e));
  if(r && r.length ) {
    return r.reduce((a, c) => a += Number(c));
  } else {
    return '';
  }
}
```

Comment: This method is work but if I remove number between cells give wrong result. or if I jump cell don't calculate next cells

Comment: After I remove all cells value the formula give me `#ERROR!` `TypeError: Reduce of empty array with no initial value (line 16).` I try to use if condition but not work `if (a== ""){
    return "";
  } else {
    return a.flat().filter(e => e && !isNaN(e)).reduce((a, c) => a += Number(c));
  }`